# How do i set the % mode switch in DDMathParser

Tags: ios, ddmathparser

I am trying to use the DDMathParser in my application, and am having difficulty in getting it to work with % symbol as percent, instead of modulo.

The wiki advises the following -

The % sign is usually interpreted as the modulo operator. However, DDMathParser.h defines a compile-time switch (DD_INTERPRET_PERCENT_SIGN_AS_MOD) that allows you to change it to be interpreted as a percentageI

I added this define in the DDMathParser.h , but it hasn't worked.
expressions are still calculated as modulo, and this is not the result i would like.

Does anybody have any experience of this, and know specifically how to set this up?

Please advise

Comment: Did you end up resolving this?

Comment: no i gave up - emailed the developer with no response

Comment: So what did you go with as an alternative, or was your project abandoned to forever collect meta-dust? ;-)

Comment: i just haven't implemented the % function i wanted to use - ddmathparser still used for other functions, just can't get my head around the % switching yet - when i finally get it sorted, i'll post the solution here if i can

Comment: Great. Look forward to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
[[DDMathOperatorSet defaultOperatorSet] setInterpretsPercentSignAsModulo:NO];
```

Comment: Thank man, I so many times changed it in the library to make it works. :) You helped a lot :)

Comment: @AntonAnisimov How it is behaving? For my latest code of  objc Its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to resolve this. First of all, you have to add this to your code, as mentioned before:

```
[[DDMathOperatorSet defaultOperatorSet] setInterpretsPercentSignAsModulo:NO];
```

Then however, you also need to fix a bug in the DDMathParser source code. I've been using the latest available ObjectiveC version of the source, dated Nov 10, 2015, from here: https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/releases/tag/objc , and the bug is in the DDMathOperator.m

Where it says:

```
return OPERATOR(DDMathOperatorPercent, @[@"%"], BINARY, 0, LEFT);
```

change it to:

```
return OPERATOR(DDMathOperatorPercent, @[@"%"], UNARY, 0, LEFT);
```

That's it - percents calculate fine afterward.